# Sonata admin - custom menu item roles

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

how i can setup custom roles to my custom routes without sonata admin, but using sonata admin menu builder.

```
        sonata.admin.group.content:
            label:           test
            label_catalogue: test
            icon:            '<i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>'
            items:
                - route:        custom_route_1
                  label:        'custom_route_1'
                - route:        custom_route_2
                  label:        'custom_route_2'
                - route:        custom_route_3
                  label:        'custom_route_3'
```

I Want setup separate roles to each element of menu.

Answer (score 0):

you must add the option roles in your yml code  :

```
    sonata.admin.group.content:
        label:           test
        label_catalogue: test
        icon:            '<i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>'
        items:
            - route:        custom_route_1
              label:        'custom_route_1'
            - route:        custom_route_2
              label:        'custom_route_2'
            - route:        custom_route_3
              label:        'custom_route_3'
        Roles : [ROLE_X, ROLES_Y,.....]
```